Use of rnd() function in VBA
I have a custom defined function as below
Function abc(Seed As Long)
Static iset As Integer
Static gset As Double
MsgBox Rnd(Seed)
MsgBox Rnd(Seed)
abc = 0
End Function

However I get two different values of Rnd(Seed) from the MsgBox. However since I fixed the seed, I was expecting I would get same values.
Could you please help me to understand how the seed works in rnd()

This is from Excel VBA help:

Returns a Single containing a random number.
Syntax
Rnd[(number)]
The optional number argument is a Single or any valid numeric expression.
Return Values



If number is
Rnd generates




Greater than zero
The next random number in the sequence.


Not supplied
The next random number in the sequence.


Less than zero
The same number every time, using number as the seed.


Equal to zero
The most recently generated number.




According to this you need to apply the bolded text.
